# cluster-wide undefined behaviour [threadName=data-streamer-stripe

Tags: ignite

I'm actually trying to load ca. 5'000'0000 records. After a while (500'000 records) I'm getting the following message

SEVERE: Blocked system-critical thread has been detected. This can lead to cluster-wide undefined behaviour [threadName=data-streamer-stripe-2, blockedFor=17s]
rto_1         | Mar 08, 2020 5:02:08 PM java.util.logging.LogManager$RootLogger log
rto_1         | SEVERE: Critical system error detected. Will be handled accordingly to configured handler [hnd=StopNodeOrHaltFailureHandler [tryStop=false, timeout=0, super=AbstractFailureHandler [ignoredFailureTypes=[SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, SYSTEM_CRITICAL_OPERATION_TIMEOUT]]], failureCtx=FailureContext [type=SYSTEM_WORKER_BLOCKED, err=class o.a.i.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=data-streamer-stripe-2, igniteInstanceName=39d7b944-fb1a-4413-80a6-a8e42679965a, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1583686911068]]]
rto_1         | class org.apache.ignite.IgniteException: GridWorker [name=data-streamer-stripe-2, igniteInstanceName=39d7b944-fb1a-4413-80a6-a8e42679965a, finished=false, heartbeatTs=1583686911068]
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1831)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.internal.IgnitionEx$IgniteNamedInstance$2.apply(IgnitionEx.java:1826)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.internal.worker.WorkersRegistry.onIdle(WorkersRegistry.java:233)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.onIdle(GridWorker.java:297)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.lambda$new$0(ServerImpl.java:2663)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:7181)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$RingMessageWorker.body(ServerImpl.java:2700)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.internal.util.worker.GridWorker.run(GridWorker.java:120)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.spi.discovery.tcp.ServerImpl$MessageWorkerThread.body(ServerImpl.java:7119)
rto_1         |         at org.apache.ignite.spi.IgniteSpiThread.run(IgniteSpiThread.java:62)

I tried to do the import on the server node and then I have switched to a dedicated client node. Independent of the setup, it seems like the streaming threads are taking suddenly several seconds. I have also tried to set the DataStreamerThreadPoolSize to 4 and StreamerNodeBufferSize to 200 so that the write can completed much faster. Without any success.

Any suggestions how to solve this problem?

Comment: Can you share the complete log? Also, you could try disabling [failure handler](https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling) completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this may be related to "Critical worker threads liveness check"

try setting necessary values for one of the following configuration.

```
1) see if you can disable Disk Persistence (if enabled)

// submit data to nodes after this time
2) IgniteDataStreamer.autoFlushFrequency(100);

// Maximum number of parallel stream operations for a single node.
3) IgniteDataStreamer.perNodeParallelOperations(48);

// disable write-through behavior
4) IgniteDataStreamer.skipStore(true); 

// Allow overwrite, false to no-overwrite
5) IgniteDataStreamer.allowOverwrite(true);
```

if you did not find any root cause, then at-least find the root cause with error handling.

https://apacheignite.readme.io/docs/critical-failures-handling

Comment: You are right that all the proposed settings by you would increase the performance. In my case I need the disk persistence. The persistence was not the main source of the problem. It was the transaction level TRANSACTIONAL_SNAPSHOT

Comment: The skipStore works for cache not with external storage.